# Another PowerShell function return value and Write-Output

Tags: powershell

this has been beaten to death but can't find an exact solution for my problem.

I have a PowerShell script that can be run from the command line or from a scheduled task. I'm using the following line

```
Write-Output "Updating user $account" | Tee-Object $logfile -Append
```

to write relevant information to the screen and a log file. I need both because when run from a command line, I can physically see what's going on but when run from a scheduled task, I have no visibility to its output hence the log file.

Thing is, I'm modifying my code to use functions but as you might already know, Write-Output messes up the return values of functions when used within said functions.

What could I do that would do something similar to what I stated above without affecting the function's return value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just write to a log file. When running from the console, open another console and `tail` the log file.

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\the\logfile.txt' -Tail 10 -Wait
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sounds like a workable solution. Only issue I see is the log file isn't created until the script is ran. Its name is the current date/time at the start of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming PowerShell version 5 or higher, where [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) writes to the [information output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) (stream number `6`), which doesn't interfere with the *success* output stream (stream number `1`) and therefore doesn't pollute your function's *data* output:

The following is not a *single* command, but you could easily wrap this in a function:

```
Write-Host "Updating user $account" -iv msg; $msg >> $logfile
```

The above uses the [common `-InformationVariable` (`-iv`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-informationvariable) to capture `Write-Host`'s output in variable `$msg` (note how its *name* must be passed to `-iv`, i.e. *without* the leading `$`).

The message captured in `$msg` is then appended to file `$logfile` with `>>`, the [appending redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection).

- Note: `>>` is in effect an alias for [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) `-Append`, and uses a *fixed* character encoding, both on creation and appending.
- Use [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) and its `-Encoding` parameter instead, if you want to control the encoding.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Sylvain. Allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment:

Answer (score 1):

Instead of explicitly writing each log line to a file, you may want to use a  different approach that references the log file only at one location in the code.

**Advantages:**

- Easy to change log path and customize the log output (e. g. prepending a timestamp), without having to modify all code locations that log something.
- Captures any kind of messages, e. g. also error, verbose and debug messages (if enabled).
- Captures messages of 3rd party code aswell, without having to tell them the name of the log file.

```
Function SomeFunction {
    Write-Host "Hello from SomeFunction"   # a log message

    "SomeFunctionOutput"  # Implicit output (return value) of the function.
                          # This is short for Write-Output "SomeFunctionOutput".
}

Function Main {
    Write-Host "Hello from Main"   # a log message

    # Call SomeFunction and store its result (aka output) in $x
    $x = SomeFunction

    # To demonstrate that "normal" function output is not affected by log messages
    $x -eq "SomeFunctionOutput"
}

# Call Main and redirect all of its output streams, including those of any 
# called functions.
Main *>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath $PSScriptRoot\Log.txt -Append
```

**Output:**

```text
Hello from Main
Hello from SomeFunction      
True
```

In this sample all code is wrapped in function `Main`. This allows us to easily redirect all [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.2) using the `*>&1` syntax, which employs the [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2) to "merge" the streams. This means that all commands further down the pipeline (in this example `Tee-Object`) receive any script messages that would normally end up in the console (except when [written directly to the console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=net-5.0), which circumvents PowerShells streams).

**Possible further improvements**

You may want to use `try`/`catch` in function `Main`, so you also capture script-terminating errors:

```
try {
    SomeFunction  # May also cause a script-terminating error, which will be catched.

    # Example code that causes a script-terminating error
    Write-Error "Fatal error" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    # Make sure script-terminating errors are logged
    Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_ -ErrorAction Continue
}
```